# Laravel Nova: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

A bunch of my Nova ressources stopped working. When trying to create them, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
at a.<anonymous> (app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1)
at y (app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1)
at Generator._invoke (app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1)
at Generator.e.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://url/vendor/nova/app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1:460720)
at o (app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1)
at app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at new t (app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1)
at a.<anonymous> (app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1)
at a.<anonymous> (app.js?id=7319bf5027431449796c:1)
```

Nothing shows up in the error log at all. Any pointers to where I should be looking? Only affects some ressources, others are working fine.

Edit: Here is one of the affected Nova ressources:

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\BelongsTo;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\HasMany;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
use Naxon\NovaFieldSortable\Concerns\SortsIndexEntries;
use Naxon\NovaFieldSortable\Sortable;

class Unterprodukt extends Resource
{
    use SortsIndexEntries;
    public static $defaultSortField = 'order';

    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = 'App\Unterprodukt';

    /**
     * Get the displayble label of the resource.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function label()
    {
        return 'Unterprodukte';
    }

    /**
     * Get the displayble singular label of the resource.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function singularLabel()
    {
        return 'Unterprodukt';
    }

    /**
     * The logical group associated with the resource.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $group = 'Versicherung';

    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'name';

    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [
        'id',
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()
                ->sortable()
                ->hideFromIndex(),

            Text::make('Name', 'name')
                ->sortable(),

            BelongsTo::make('Produkt', 'produkt', 'App\Nova\Produkt')
                ->sortable(),

            Sortable::make('Reihenfolge', 'id')
                ->sortable(),

            HasMany::make('Dokumente', 'dokumente', 'App\Nova\Dokument'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the cards available for the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the lenses available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function lenses(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the actions available for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change anything before this happened? Do you have any xhr request that return a server error?

Comment: This is a project I'm currently building, so changes have definitely been made to a lot of things. But I'm not sure when the error started appearing, which is why I'm trying to narrow it down. There is nothing showing up in the network tab, so it seems like there is no communication happening with the server.

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix for this is this way

```
Sortable::make('Order', 'id')->exceptOnForms()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it was because I had an incoherence between nova fields and migrations fields.

Now, another possible way to fix it is:

```
php artisan nova:publish
php artisan view:clear
```

Check this issue for more details: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1735